# Python: lxml is not reading element text all time

Tags: python, pandas, lxml

I want to load xml file with below structure into pandas dataframe

The size of xml could be between 1 GB to 6GB

Below xml sample just have 5 records but my acutal file will have around 100000 records as mention in the RECORDS attributes below (RECORDS="108881")

Also each and every element in this file will have some value.
None of the element is empty in the whole file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ACADEMICS>  
   <STUDENTS ASOF_DATE="11/21/2019" CREATE_DATE="11/22/2019" RECORDS="108881">      
    <STUDENT>      
        <NAME>JOHN</NAME>      
        <REGNUM>1000</REGNUM>      
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>      
        <ID>JH1</ID>
        <SHORT_STD_DESC>JOHN IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>      
        <NAME>ADAM</NAME>      
        <REGNUM>1001</REGNUM>      
        <COUNTRY>FRANCE</COUNTRY>      
        <ID>AD2</ID>
        <SHORT_STD_DESC>ADAM IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>      
        <NAME>PETER</NAME>      
        <REGNUM>1003</REGNUM>      
        <COUNTRY>BELGIUM</COUNTRY>      
        <ID>PE5</ID>
        <SHORT_STD_DESC>PETER IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>      
        <NAME>ERIC</NAME>      
        <REGNUM>1006</REGNUM>      
        <COUNTRY>AUSTRALIA</COUNTRY>      
        <ID>ER7</ID>
        <SHORT_STD_DESC>ERIC IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>      
        <NAME>NICHOLAS</NAME>      
        <REGNUM>1009</REGNUM>      
        <COUNTRY>GREECE</COUNTRY>      
        <ID>NI8</ID>
        <SHORT_STD_DESC>NICHOLAS IS A GOOD STUDENT</SHORT_STD_DESC>
    </STUDENT>
</STUDENTS>
```

i am trying to read these xmls with lxml as below functions
As you can see in below functions, i am just interested in reading specific tags from xml file which are ["ACADEMICS","STUDENDS","ID","SHORT_STD_DESC"]

```
def recursive_dict(self,element):
        return element.tag, \
            dict(map(self.recursive_dict, element)) or element.text

def ConvertFilePivot(self, inputfile):        
        context = etree.iterparse(inputfile, events=('start','end'), tag=["ACADEMICS","STUDENDS","ID","SHORT_STD_DESC"])
        lstValues = []
        asOfDate = ""
        for event, elem in context:
            if elem.tag == "ACADEMICS" :
                asOfDate = elem[0].attrib['ASOF_DATE']
            else:        
                for event, elem in context:                                          
                    doc = self.recursive_dict(elem)                                   
                    lstValues.append(doc)                
                dfvalues = pd.DataFrame(lstValues,columns=["ColName","ColValue"])
                columns = dfvalues['ColName'].unique()
                data = {}
                for column in columns:
                    data[column] = list(dfvalues[dfvalues['ColName'] == column]['ColValue'])

        dfdata = pd.DataFrame(data)        
        return dfdata
```

Now, the problem is when i load this xml into dataframe as shown in above function, for some records i get 'None' as a text for ID and  SHORT_STD_DESC elements.
But the actual xml file has that value.
So i am not sure why it is not reflected in my dataframe ?
Any input would be great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be more a comment than an answer, but I can't fit it in an actual comment...

Try changing

```
 else:        
     for event, elem in context:                                          
           doc = self.recursive_dict(elem)
```

to just:

```
 else:             
     doc = self.recursive_dict(elem)
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack, this fixed my issue. I was scratching my head since last few days to fix it.